# Стандартный модуль zipfile. Не найду класс class zipfile.Path(root, at='')

Tags: python, zipfile

В [документации по модулю zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html?highlight=class%20zipfile%20path#zipfile.Path.exists)  присутствует [описание](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile%20path#zipfile.Path) класса `class zipfile.Path(root, at='')`. Однако я не могу его найти. Поиск "в лоб":

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> dir(zipfile)
['BZIP2_VERSION',
 'BadZipFile',
 'BadZipfile',
 'DEFAULT_VERSION',
 'LZMACompressor',
 'LZMADecompressor',
 'LZMA_VERSION',
 'LargeZipFile',
 'MAX_EXTRACT_VERSION',
 'PyZipFile',
 'ZIP64_LIMIT',
 'ZIP64_VERSION',
 'ZIP_BZIP2',
 'ZIP_DEFLATED',
 'ZIP_FILECOUNT_LIMIT',
 'ZIP_LZMA',
 'ZIP_MAX_COMMENT',
 'ZIP_STORED',
 'ZipExtFile',
 'ZipFile',
 'ZipInfo',
 '_CD64_CREATE_VERSION',
 '_CD64_DIRECTORY_RECSIZE',
 '_CD64_DIRECTORY_SIZE',
 '_CD64_DISK_NUMBER',
 '_CD64_DISK_NUMBER_START',
 '_CD64_EXTRACT_VERSION',
 '_CD64_NUMBER_ENTRIES_THIS_DISK',
 '_CD64_NUMBER_ENTRIES_TOTAL',
 '_CD64_OFFSET_START_CENTDIR',
 '_CD64_SIGNATURE',
 '_CD_COMMENT_LENGTH',
 '_CD_COMPRESSED_SIZE',
 '_CD_COMPRESS_TYPE',
 '_CD_CRC',
 '_CD_CREATE_SYSTEM',
 '_CD_CREATE_VERSION',
 '_CD_DATE',
 '_CD_DISK_NUMBER_START',
 '_CD_EXTERNAL_FILE_ATTRIBUTES',
 '_CD_EXTRACT_SYSTEM',
 '_CD_EXTRACT_VERSION',
 '_CD_EXTRA_FIELD_LENGTH',
 '_CD_FILENAME_LENGTH',
 '_CD_FLAG_BITS',
 '_CD_INTERNAL_FILE_ATTRIBUTES',
 '_CD_LOCAL_HEADER_OFFSET',
 '_CD_SIGNATURE',
 '_CD_TIME',
 '_CD_UNCOMPRESSED_SIZE',
 '_DD_SIGNATURE',
 '_ECD_COMMENT',
 '_ECD_COMMENT_SIZE',
 '_ECD_DISK_NUMBER',
 '_ECD_DISK_START',
 '_ECD_ENTRIES_THIS_DISK',
 '_ECD_ENTRIES_TOTAL',
 '_ECD_LOCATION',
 '_ECD_OFFSET',
 '_ECD_SIGNATURE',
 '_ECD_SIZE',
 '_EXTRA_FIELD_STRUCT',
 '_EndRecData',
 '_EndRecData64',
 '_FH_COMPRESSED_SIZE',
 '_FH_COMPRESSION_METHOD',
 '_FH_CRC',
 '_FH_EXTRACT_SYSTEM',
 '_FH_EXTRACT_VERSION',
 '_FH_EXTRA_FIELD_LENGTH',
 '_FH_FILENAME_LENGTH',
 '_FH_GENERAL_PURPOSE_FLAG_BITS',
 '_FH_LAST_MOD_DATE',
 '_FH_LAST_MOD_TIME',
 '_FH_SIGNATURE',
 '_FH_UNCOMPRESSED_SIZE',
 '_SharedFile',
 '_Tellable',
 '_ZipDecrypter',
 '_ZipWriteFile',
 '__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 '_check_compression',
 '_check_zipfile',
 '_crctable',
 '_gen_crc',
 '_get_compressor',
 '_get_decompressor',
 '_strip_extra',
 'binascii',
 'bz2',
 'compressor_names',
 'crc32',
 'error',
 'importlib',
 'io',
 'is_zipfile',
 'lzma',
 'main',
 'os',
 'shutil',
 'sizeCentralDir',
 'sizeEndCentDir',
 'sizeEndCentDir64',
 'sizeEndCentDir64Locator',
 'sizeFileHeader',
 'stat',
 'stringCentralDir',
 'stringEndArchive',
 'stringEndArchive64',
 'stringEndArchive64Locator',
 'stringFileHeader',
 'struct',
 'structCentralDir',
 'structEndArchive',
 'structEndArchive64',
 'structEndArchive64Locator',
 'structFileHeader',
 'sys',
 'threading',
 'time',
 'zlib']
```

Особо не помог. А возможности этого класса - судя по описанию - заманчивые. Не подскажите - где искать, как использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже вы используете Python версии < 3.8.

[Выдержка из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html):

> ```
> class zipfile.Path
> ```
>
> A pathlib-compatible wrapper for zip files. See section Path Objects
>   for details.
>
> **New in version 3.8.**

Comment: )))))))))))))))))))))))
таки да )))))))))))